# How do I find the number-palindrome if a large number causes the size exceeded collstack to overflow?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callstack

I try to find a palindrome number, but if the number I pass is too big, then the call stack overflows.
How can this be fixed so that the function can return larger numbers?

```js
(function () {
  function checkPalindrome(num) {
    let palindromeResult = {
      result: 0,
      steps: 0,
    };

    function iterNum(num2) {
      let reverseNum = Number(num2.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));

      if (num2 === reverseNum) {
        palindromeResult.result = num2;
        return num2;
      }

      if (num2 !== reverseNum) {
        num2 += reverseNum;
        palindromeResult.steps++;
        iterNum(num2);
      }
    }
    iterNum(num);
    return palindromeResult;
  }

  console.log(checkPalindrome(213132424143132131));
})();
```

Comment: Work with strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Is there a mathematical prove that the sum of a number and its reverse will finally be a palindrome? I think that your code may just never end

Comment: @Pointy But I only want numbers. What can I do in this case?

Comment: @Dunker there is a limit of how big numbers can be in programming languages. When your numbers are bigger than this limit comparison stops working. There is not really other way than using a string at some point

Comment: @Dunker you can try bigint values (where they're supported, which is mostly everywhere now). `1232343454565676787890n` is an example. Of course, the first thing your code does is turn it into a string anyway, so I don't see what difference it makes.